# Can i create new calculate member on dimension in SSAS?

Tags: ssas

I have created a cube using FactFinance table. I have created calculate member on Measures. I just want to know that, can i create calculate member on dimension table?

If yes, Can you tell the steps?

I am confused about parent hierarchy & parent member. I tried by selecting DimTime.CalendarYear in parent hierarchy, but it returns an error in parent member. Nothing is visible. PLease help. I am completly new to this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Create calculated members on dimension tables in the data source view.